# Folder structure, C#

Tags: c#, directory-structure

Folder structure in a project file has been discussed here several time, but I would like to narrow down the question further. Say for example, my project is organized in the following way with respective namespaces

```
[Project 1]  

[A(Folder)]    
   Class A             ConceptCheck.ClassA
   [B(Folder)] 
     Class B           ConceptCheck.ClassA.ClassB
[C(Folder)]
   Class C             ConceptCheck.ClassC
```

So when I create objects as below I need to include all the namespaces

```
using ConceptCheck.ClassA;
using ConceptCheck.ClassB;
using ConceptCheck.ClassA.ClassC;

            A a = new A();
            B b = new B();
            C c = new C();
```

For example if it small amount of namespaces, I can do it easily. I would like to know what is the best way, If the number of namespaces are high? Is it a best way of including namespaces like this?

Comment: What you have seems fine.  The number of namespaces doesn't slow down performance, and it generally shouldn't slow down development.  P.S. you may gain insite from this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having followed what's been said here before, I think you're better off naming  name spaces not after folders or even projects, but in such a way, that encompasses classes that belong together logically (from system/functional perspective).

For example you may have several projects - each implementing a particular external API. Functionally similar, doing the same thing for your system, just different flavors. Say banking statement downloads. Your project structure may look something like this:

```
Project BankA 
   class BankADownloader
Project BankB 
   BankBDownloader
   HelperA
   ExtensionsB
Project BankC
   ...
```

It makes sense to use same namespace for all such projects, for example MySystem.StatementDownloaders

I am giving an opinion using even broader example - multiple projects. But this applies full force to one projects with many folders. To use my Bank-Statement-Downloader example, you may want to organize classes and other artifacts into folders (by Bank), but again, the namespaces, IMO, should reflect common functionality (or other logical architecture perspective - like app tier), rather than folder-organization.

I hope I am not misinterpreting your question.

Comment: I agree with your view. We should organize based on the functionality

Comment: I agree that namespaces should be named according to a logical functional grouping of the objects that they contain. But then I wonder, why should folders be named otherwise?